# Create a button that will sort a MYSQL query ascending and descending

Tags: php, mysql, dom-events

I'm a student coder.
I want to create a sort button that when pressed, sorts a MYSQL query in Ascending order. Then when pressed again, it will sort in Descending order. Right, now, it just shows both Ascending and Descending tables back to back.

What's the best way to form this button's logic?

```
  <form name="Email Header" method="post" action="{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}">
    <button type="submit" name="id_sort" class="button" value="1">ID</button>
    <button type="submit" name="from_sort" class="button" value="1">FROM</button>
    <button type="submit" name="to_sort" class="button" value="1">TO</button>
    <button type="submit" name="subject_sort" class="button" value="1">SUBJECT</button>
    <button type="submit" name="date_sort" class="button" value="1">DATE</button>
 </form>


// SORT 

if( isset( $_POST['id_sort'] ) )
   if( $_POST['id_sort'] == 1 )
     id_ASC_sort();
     $_POST['id_sort'] = 0;

if ($_POST['id_sort'] == 0)
  if( isset( $_POST['id_sort'] ) )
     if( $_POST['id_sort'] == 1 ) 
        id_DESC_sort();


 // query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY message_id DESC";
    $result = mysql_query( $sql );
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your second conditional block. You've got a single equals sign instead of a double equals sign. That means you're actually *setting* the variable rather than checking its value, which always evaluates to true.

Comment: I corrected the == issue. How do I get a button to sort ascending and when pressed again, to sort descending? Thanks.

Comment: Since you're reloading the page every time, I'd suggest checking the posted sort value and setting the value of the button to the reverse, e.g., `value="<?php echo(1-$id_sort) ?>"`. That way the button will request an ascending sort if the previous sort was descending, and vice versa.

Comment: It looks like id_sort is a function, not a variable. Did you make a typo? Btw, how would you do the echo of the button value if it were in a heredoc?

Comment: No, it's meant to be a variable. I was using it as shorthand for the value you have in $_POST['id_sort']. That's actually also the answer to your other question: If you save the value to a local variable, you can then include that variable in a heredoc string, and it will automatically substitute the value (it only does this for simple variables, not for values taken from an array. So $id_sort will work, but $_POST['id_sort'] won't).

Answer (score 0):

I have change below line in your code:-

```
<form name="Email Header" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

And Added one button:-

```
<button type="submit" name="asc_sort" id="asc_sort" class="button" value="1">Sort</button>
```

and Change Query

```
if(isset($_POST['asc_sort']) && !empty($_POST['asc_sort']) && $_POST['asc_sort']==1)
{
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY message_id ASC";

}else{

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY message_id DESC";
}

echo $sql;
```

Try This

```
<form name="Email Header" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<button type="submit" name="id_sort" class="button" value="1">ID</button>
<button type="submit" name="from_sort" class="button" value="1">FROM</button>
<button type="submit" name="to_sort" class="button" value="1">TO</button>
<button type="submit" name="subject_sort" class="button" value="1">SUBJECT</button>
<button type="submit" name="date_sort" class="button" value="1">DATE</button>
<button type="submit" name="asc_sort" id="asc_sort" class="button" value="1">Sort</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, Abid. Instead of using a up and a down link, I would like one button that can sort up (ascending), then the value of the same button changes to down so that I can press it again and get a down (descending sort)

Comment: Abid, thanks for responding again. This is 2 buttons doing different sorts. I really want one button to do ASC sort and DESC sort. Thanks.